# Log changes to multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, logging

I found this code on this forum to log changes to multiple cells to a sheet called "LOG". Not sure how it work but it works great. However, the log showed in single cell on the "LOG" sheet. Is there a way to modify the code so information appear in "LOG" sheet in different row such as date/time in row A, user in row B, etc. Also, can I add to the code so that the sheet "LOG" is password protect from user (but still adding log). Here's the code. Thank you for any help.

```
Dim RangeValues As Variant
Dim lCols As Long, lRows As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.Value <> RangeValues Then
        Sheets("LOG").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now & " / " & UN & " / changed cell " & Target.Address & "  /from/ " & RangeValues & " to " & Target.Value
    End If
    Exit Sub
End If
' More than one cell in the range
Dim r As Long, c As Long
For r = 1 To lRows
    For c = 1 To lCols
        If Target.Cells(r, c).Value <> RangeValues(r, c) Then
            Sheets("LOG").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now & " / " & UN & " / changed cell " & Target.Cells(r, c).Address & "  /from/ " & RangeValues(r, c) & " to " & Target.Cells(r, c).Value
        End If
    Next c
Next r
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
RangeValues = Target.Value
lCols = Target.Columns.Count
lRows = Target.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next updated solution:

```
Option Explicit

Dim RangeValues As Variant
Dim lCols As Long, lRows As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("LOG_")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.userName
 If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 5) = Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To")
 sh.Unprotect "1234" 'use here your real password
 If Target.cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.value <> RangeValues Then
        sh.cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 5).value = _
                 Array(Now, UN, Target.Address(0, 0), RangeValues, Target.value)
    End If
    Exit Sub
 End If
 ' More than one cell in the range
 Dim r As Long, c As Long
 For r = 1 To lRows
    For c = 1 To lCols
        If Target.cells(r, c).value <> RangeValues(r, c) Then
            sh.cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 5).value = _
                 Array(Now, UN, Target.cells(r, c).Address(0, 0), RangeValues(r, c), Target.cells(r, c).value)
        End If
    Next c
 Next r
 sh.Protect "1234"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   RangeValues = Target.value
   lCols = Target.Columns.Count
   lRows = Target.rows.Count
End Sub
```

In fact, only `Worksheet_Change` event has been changed and added `Option Explicit` on top of the module.

**Edited**:

Please, use the next code. It uses only an event and no necessary to previously select the range where to copy:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim RangeValues As Variant, lCols As Long, lRows As Long
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("LOG_")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.userName
 If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 5) = Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To")
 sh.Unprotect "1234" 'use here your real password
 
 Dim TgValue 'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False               'to optimize the code (make it faster)
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 TgValue = Target.value
 Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Undo
  RangeValues = Range(Target.Address).value 'define the RangeValue
  lCols = Target.Columns.Count
  lRows = Target.rows.Count
  Range(Target.Address).value = TgValue 'Put back the Target value (changed using UnDo)
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 
 'One cell in the range
 If Target.cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.value <> RangeValues Then
        sh.cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 5).value = _
                 Array(Now, UN, Target.Address(0, 0), RangeValues, Target.value)
    End If
     sh.Protect "1234"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Exit Sub
 End If
 ' More than one cell in the range
 Dim r As Long, c As Long
 For r = 1 To lRows
    For c = 1 To lCols
        If Target.cells(r, c).value <> RangeValues(r, c) Then
            sh.cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 5).value = _
                 Array(Now, UN, Target.cells(r, c).Address(0, 0), RangeValues(r, c), Target.cells(r, c).value)
        End If
    Next c
 Next r
 sh.Protect "1234"
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**Second edit:**

The version able to deal with continuous ranges, but built by consecutively selecting cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim RangeValues As Variant, lCols As Long, lRows As Long, contRng As Range
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("LOG_")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.userName
 If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 5) = Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To")
 sh.Unprotect "" 'use here your real password
 
 Dim TgValue 'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False               'to optimize the code (make it faster)
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 If Target.cells.Count > 1 Then
    TgValue = Range(Target.Address).value
    If Not IsArray(TgValue) Then            'if the range is discontinuous and its first area means single cell
        Set contRng = ContRange(Target) 'the discontinuous range is transformed in continuous
        TgValue = contRng.value             'only now the range value can be (correctly) put in an array
        Set Target = contRng                  'the target range is also built as continuous
       ' Debug.Print "Target =  " & Target.Address: 'Stop
    Else
       Set contRng = Target                   'for continuous ranges, even made of a single cell
    End If
 Else
    TgValue = Target.value             'put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    Set contRng = Target               'set contRng (to be used later) as Target
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = False                       'avoiding to trigger the change event after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = Range(contRng.Address).value 'define the RangeValue
     'If IsArray(RangeValues) Then Debug.Print RangeValues(1, 1): ' Stop
     lCols = Target.Columns.Count                      'extract the target number of rows and columns:
     lRows = Target.rows.Count
     Range(Target.Address).value = TgValue         'Put back the Target value (changed using UnDo)
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 'One cell in the range
 If Target.cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.value <> RangeValues Then
        sh.cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 5).value = _
                 Array(Now, UN, Target.Address(0, 0), RangeValues, Target.value)
    End If
     sh.Protect ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Exit Sub
 End If
 ' More than one cell in the range
 Dim r As Long, c As Long
 For r = 1 To lRows
    For c = 1 To lCols
        If Target.cells(r, c).value <> RangeValues(r, c) Then
            sh.cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 5).value = _
                 Array(Now, UN, Target.cells(r, c).Address(0, 0), RangeValues(r, c), Target.cells(r, c).value)
        End If
    Next c
 Next r
 sh.Protect ""
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Function ContRange(rng As Range) As Range
    Dim a As Range, rngCont As Range
    
    For Each a In rng.Areas
        If rngCont Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCont = a
        Else
           Set rngCont = Union(rngCont, a)
        End If
    Next
    If Not rngCont Is Nothing Then Set ContRange = rngCont
End Function
```

The code can be adapted to also handle real discontinue ranges, but it is a little more complicated and no interested in taking such a challenge...

**Third edit**:

The next version, follow a different logic and is able to log all kind of modifications, even in discontinuous ranges:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("LOG_")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.userName
 
 If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6) = _
                                     Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To", "Sheet Name")
 sh.Unprotect "" 'use here your real password

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False                             'to optimize the code (make it faster)
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 If Target.cells.count > 1 Then
    TgValue = extractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = False                               'avoiding to trigger the change event after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = extractData(Target)                                 'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                           'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
        sh.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).value = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), Target.Parent.Name)
    End If
 Next r
 
 sh.Protect ""
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
    For Each El In arr
        sh.Range(El(1)).value = El(0)
    Next
End Sub
Function extractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas
            For i = 1 To a.cells.count
                arr(count) = Array(a.cells(i).value, a.cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function
```

Comment: That works great! Thanks a lot. Is there a way to add .Unprotect Password:="XXX" and .Protect Password:="XXX" so that the "LOG_" sheet is automatically password protected?

Comment: @user16269017: Of course, I will adapt the above code. But, it is good to know that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works...

Comment: @user16269017: Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: I try the updated suggestion but it seems like the password protection is not working. When protecting the "LOG_" sheet before use, it doesn't unprotect and give runtime error. When I leave the "LOG_" sheet unlock, it doesn't automatically protect it. Please give suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I changed the password line in your code to sh.Unprotect Password:="1234" and sh.Protect Password:="1234" and the password protection seems to be working now. Thank you again @FaneDuru

Comment: @user16269017: I forgot to tell you that I named the sheet "LOG_" instead of "LOG" because I wonted to test the code and I already head a sheet named "LOG". Then, like I said (`'use here your real password`), you should use a password you like, But, of course, you should **firstly** manuale set it, since the code initially unprotect the worksheet...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code work! Anyway, I just found another limitation from testing it that if I pasted different range values from another workbook, the logging is not done properly. When I copied range of values from 5 cells and paste onto the sheet (the sheet with the code) by selecting 3 cells only, it only record the 3 cells I select for pasting. But new values are pasted onto 5 cells. If I simply right click on a cell and paste 5 cells values, it give Runtime error.

Comment: @user16269017 This is the logic of the code. It needs a **previous selection** from which the `SelectionChange` event memorizes the previous values. This values cannot come from other source. You must understand how the code works if you want it to not return an error, or to miss some pieces of information...

Comment: @user16269017 I never needed such a code and I did not try to evaluate it in terms of efficiency. I think I can adapt it to not need the second event (`SelectionChange`) and extract the previous range values using `UnDo`. I will post another `Worksheet_Change` in some minutes.

Comment: @FaneDuru in code of ( ' More than one Cell in the Range ..) if modified cells selected by (keeping Control) , it gives error  ( Run-time error '13': Type mismatch )

Comment: @FaneDuru I tested it by pasting values, so far so good. It record all the changes even if I selected different size of cells to paste from what I copied. Much Better! Really appreciate your help. If I want to further modify it so that it also give information of sheet name, can I just do **Resize(1, 6)** = Array("Time", "User Name", **"Sheet"**, "Changed cell", "From", "To"). Also, Array(Now, UN, **ActiveSheet.Name**, Target.Address(0, 0), RangeValues, Target.Value). Finally, Array(Now, UN, **ActiveSheet.Name**, Target.Cells(r, c).Address(0, 0), RangeValues(r, c), Target.Cells(r, c).Value).

Comment: @Waleed_wwm What does " if modified cells selected by (keeping Control) , it gives error..." mean?

Comment: @Faneduru. I selected two cells with Ctrl pressed , then I deleted those two cells ( no matter if those cells are continuous or not)

Comment: @Waleed_wwm When you consecutively select cells VBA considers the range as being discontinue. Even if the selected cells are in a continuous range. The code can be adapted to solve this aspect, too, I think, but not time for that. I do not need such a code...

Comment: @Waleed_wwm I have some time now and I will take the challenge to adapt the code to also log the ranges built by consecutive selections, which VBA treats as discontinuous. The trick should be to create a function able to make the range continuous. I am talking (now) about the consecutive selected cells **being part of a continuous range**. The code should be able to also log real discontinuous ranges, but it is more complicate and not needing of such a code, not interested in such a challenge...

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: @FaneDure. Now It works with continuous ranges without problem ( with CTRL Hold) , same problem with discontinuous ranges. anyway , Many thanks for all your great support

Comment: @Waleed_wwm I am back, at home and I will try the version able to log all kind of changes, even deleting of a discontinuous range...

Comment: @FaneDure. Third edit has duplicate codes . anyway, I removed the first code (assumed it is the old ) . Now your code works perfectly with any range status 

Comment: @Waleed_wwm I corrected the third edit. Yes, I copied the previous (cancelled by adding XX at the event name) by mistake...

Comment: @FaneDuru you nailed it! I tested it. The third edit is just flawless. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user16269017: Since I tried making it working as I suppose it should, I also modified the code to make the selection jumping down when press Enter (after modification) and adding the sheet name in the sixth column (as you were asking for, but in a different column). Pease, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @FaneDuru: as mentioned your code works perfectly.  I adopted the code little ( in second edit ) to my specific needs according to my skills (But I couldn't do with third edit)  ,So kindly should I ask here or open a new Question .

Comment: @user16269017: Not available too much right now... But it will be good to place a new question, posting my code and explaining how do you like it to be adapted. If you tag me (here) and I will be available, I will help with pleasure. If not available, most probably somebody else will solve it... In principle, I only created a new Boolean variable, to detect one cell modification, and select the cell bellow it (using Offset) for such a case. About the sheet name logging, you already understood the logic, I think.

Comment: @FaneDuru  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68084139/how-to-get-vaule-of-first-cell-of-row-and-column-to-put-in-array-excel-vba

Comment: @user16269017: I could see your question, but I couldn't understand what you need...

Comment: @FaneDuru That's very kind of you for further editing to make it even better. I noticed in the previous code that when pressing enter the cell selection remain the same. I could ignore the issue as it didn't affect the change logging. Anyway, now you fixed that too! I tested it and didn't see any issue so far. Great! Thanks.