# How to extract ( first cell of row and column ) of modified cells to put in array, excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code Log changes of sheet (depend on Worksheet_Change ) and put on another sheet "Log " onto multiple cells . the code works flawlessly , But I need to adapt it to **get vaule of first Cell of row(s) and column(s) to put in this part of code array**
for example,  if the changed values are E4, D5, I would like to place in the array, the next pieces of information "E1","D1"  "A4","A5"

```
sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).value = _
Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), Target.Parent.name)
```

I tried `Target.EntireRow.Cells(1) and Target.EntireColumn.Cells(1)` but it is not reliable and not works with multi cells . any help will be appreciated.
[image]
this the full code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("Log")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
    TgValue = extractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = False                               'avoiding to trigger the change event after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = extractData(Target)                                 'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                           'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
        sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).value = _
          Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), Target.Parent.name)
        
    End If
 Next r
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
    For Each El In arr
        sh.Range(El(1)).value = El(0)
    Next
End Sub

Function extractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.Cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas
            For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
                arr(count) = Array(a.Cells(i).value, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function
```

Comment: I am afraid I cannot understand which is your need... I cannot understand what "**get vaule of first Cell of row(s) and column(s) to put in this part of code array**" means. Please, try an example if the changed values are A5, A6, B5 and B6, I would like to place in the array, on the following column, the next pieces of information "..." .

Comment: Or try any other example, more convenient to you, but able to clarify what you need.

Comment: @ FaneDuru , Please see attached photo , modified cells in yellow

Comment: OK. Now, it is a little clearer... I mean it is not complicated to extract that values and place in the specific array. Now, what about modifying of **these specific** cells? The event must be adapted in order to log  everything except the first column and first tow rows (as I can see from your picture). Doesn't it sound logic?

Comment: @ FaneDuru ,it is just a piece of sheet , there is no exceptions on the event

Comment: So, what to place the code in the array if A4 from the Colum A:A will be changed from 4 to 20? And also, if "Location" in the first two merged rows will be changed in "Something else"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next updated code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("LOG_")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.userName
 
 'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub      'not doing anything if a cell in A:A is changed
 'If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("1:2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'Not doing anything if a cell is changed in first two rows
  sh.Unprotect "" 'use here your real password
 If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 8) = _
                                     Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To", "Sheet Name", "Row label", "Colum label")

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                     'to optimize the code (make it faster)
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 If Target.cells.count > 1 Then
    TgValue = extractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = False                                        'avoiding to trigger the change event after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = extractData(Target)                                 'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                                  'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
 For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
        columnHeader = cells(1, Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Column).value
        rowHeader = Range("A" & Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).row).value
        sh.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8).value = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), Target.Parent.Name, rowHeader, columnHeader)
    End If
 Next r
 
 sh.Protect ""
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
    For Each El In arr
        sh.Range(El(1)).value = El(0)
    Next
End Sub
Function extractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
            For i = 1 To a.cells.count
                arr(count) = Array(a.cells(i).value, a.cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function
```

Please, test the code and send some feedback.

If you want to **Not** allow logging of modifications in column A:A or first two merged rows, please uncomment the lines starting with `If Not Intersect(...`.  It looks strange to me to make the code logging the column/row header which has just been changed. But it is up to you, of course. You should know better what you need accomplishing...

I would suggest you to protect the working sheet, unlock all cells, then lock only A:A column and first two rows. In this way, the user cannot delete the headers which should be used as references in the logging process.

Please, unprotect he LOG_ sheet and delete the headers from the first row.

Comment: Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).row  extract row number , But the needed is extract corresponding  value on column A

Comment: I am driving now..  I will change it when I will be at home.

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Didn't you find some time to test the updated code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: sorry , all last time I was out from house . i will test now

Comment: @Waleed_wwm It is not such a big deal... I would suggest you to delete your last comment.

Comment: @FaneDuru.this a realted question, kindly help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684611/conflict-between-two-events-if-filtermode-false-and-any-cells-changed-by-fill

Comment: @FaneDuru.I managed to solve the last question by myself.It obviously, you refused to help me anymore.anyway I really appreciate all your help and wonderful answer with me last months.I will not send any type of help request to you again.

Comment: @Waleed_wwm I cannot understand your reaction... I looked to your question following the  link, I did not understand what is to be done, just looking to the question and no time for testing and asking for clarifications. I was involved in solving of two other more challenging questions and with my office problems. If you do not want asking for help, I do not have a problem...

Comment: @FaneDuru.Sorry for misunderstood you, I really appreciate all your help and wonderful answers.