# How to adapt event SelectionChange code to work in event Calculate?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code works on event `SelectionChange` without any problem at all.
But, if I moved to it event Calculate , this error appear **Method 'Undo' of object '_Application' failed** .
There is another code on Worksheet_Change , But I think it is not the cause of problem.

```
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
Dim Column_A As Range
 Set Column_A = ActiveSheet.Range("A3", ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp))
 If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
    Column_A.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else  'FilterMode = False
    Column_A.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End If
  End If
End Sub
```

I tried to use `If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1` in event Calculate  , But this error raised
**Object required**
As always, Great thanks for all your support

Comment: `Worksheet_Calculate` does not have the Target-argument. So you have to remove that row and then it should run without this error

Comment: @Ike.I removed Target but same problem. I replaced it with Selection and the code semi working , The issue now, I need to fire event Calculate only if specific cell update by formula (already found in cell AL1). How to use intersect with this issue !

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reading your post and most recent comment, I can't work out (with any certainty) what you're actually trying to do. Taking a best-guess approach, I've put together the following. It takes action in the Calculate event only when the value of cell AL1 changes as part of that Calculate.

```
Option Explicit

''' Reference value register
    Private mvnRefValue

''' Initialise Reference value when sheet first activated
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If mvnRefValue = Empty Then mvnRefValue = Range("AL1")
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim Column_A As Range

If Range("AL1") <> mvnRefValue Then
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set Column_A = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
        Column_A.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else  'FilterMode = False
        Column_A.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If

''' Update mvnRefValue
    mvnRefValue = Range("AL1")
End If

End Sub
```

If you want to test for a more more complex change scenario, adopt the notions used above as appropriate (and/or explain more fully what if is you're actually trying to do).

Comment: @Spinner.It works flawlessly , But kindly could you add comments on the code so I can understand it.BTW , the beginning of problem started here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684611/conflict-between-two-events-if-filtermode-false-and-any-cells-changed-by-fill. I managed to fix Code(1) on selectionChange event , But I couldn't make it works with calculate event. That is why, I post that question

Comment: Glad I could help :)  Bit confused re adding comments, as I did write comments to the code I added, except for one line 'If Range("AL1") <> mvnRefValue'. Thought that bit was obvious, and (in case it's not) comment would be 'Check if reference value changed'. The rest is your code, so I assume you know what it's doing. No?

Comment: @Spinner.Now all understood.